# The application does not respond after some time

Tags: android, android-studio

The application does not respond after some time when I leave the application and start it after, I do not close my application, it works in the background.
When I return to my app, I click for example element of RecyclerView nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure you're not running anything of your app's Main/UI thread and also while the app is running check you logcat for possible error pointers